# Loading jQuery based on viewport width

Tags: jquery, function, resize, viewport

I have an events calendar that shows all the days of the week in the top row. The calendar itself is responsive, but when it's shrunken down for mobile, the days of the week extend outside of their boxes, and overlap each other – which also creates some width overflow.

I would like to use jQuery to change "Sunday" to "S" when viewed on mobile, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Using the ".replaceWith" command, I've managed to get part of it to work. I just can't figure out how to trigger this script based on the browser width.

Here's my code so far:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 950) {
        $( "div.sunday" ).replaceWith( "S" );
        $( "div.monday" ).replaceWith( "M" );
        $( "div.tuesday" ).replaceWith( "T" );
        $( "div.wednesday" ).replaceWith( "W" );
        $( "div.thursday" ).replaceWith( "T" );
        $( "div.friday" ).replaceWith( "F" );
        $( "div.saturday" ).replaceWith( "S" );
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CN8Gs/1/

Comment: You're sure you shouldn't just use `text()`, and not `replaceWith()`

Comment: you aren't triggering the resize  ... `$(window).resize(handler).resize()`  http://jsfiddle.net/CN8Gs/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CN8Gs/2/

Comment: You can do the same thing with a combination of media query + html Please note that the width in js is different than the width used in media query. You might need to sync them depending on how you handle things

Comment: You missed the closing `)` for resize http://jsfiddle.net/CN8Gs/4/

Comment: @eric wood: Please don't reward Mr. Bob's bad behavior. His 1st and 2nd edits were complete garbage. Then suddenly with the third edit he has the code completely redone with the trigger call in place... Please take away your accept or delete your answer. I spent a good amount of time re-reading and rethinking your OP and had I not answered Mr. Bob would have kept running you down a rabbit hole. Does that deserve an up vote and accept? He ripped off my answer and made copying & pasting easier for you. Does that deserve an up vote and accept? Please act.

Comment: @PaulSasik - Thank you for taking the time to help me out with my issue. I didn't realize Robert was copying from your post – especially since you both provided slightly different answers. I also don't really care if he copied your post or not. I thought this community was all about coming together on issues, to find the best, most stable solutions. And if you re-read the answer you provided, you'll notice that there's a comment from me that's still unanswered (thus, leaving me with an unsolved issue, and code that doesn't do me any good). Does that deserve an up vote and accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
console.log($(window).width());
if ($(window).width() < 950) {
    $( "div.sunday" ).text( "S" );
    $( "div.monday" ).text( "M" );
    $( "div.tuesday" ).text( "T" );
    $( "div.wednesday" ).text( "W" );
    $( "div.thursday" ).text( "T" );
    $( "div.friday" ).text( "F" );
    $( "div.saturday" ).text( "S" );
}
else
{
    $( "div.sunday" ).text( "Sunday" );
    $( "div.monday" ).text( "Monday" );
    $( "div.tuesday" ).text( "Tuesday" );
    $( "div.wednesday" ).text( "Wednesday" );
    $( "div.thursday" ).text( "Thursday" );
    $( "div.friday" ).text( "Friday" );
    $( "div.saturday" ).text( "Saturday" );
 }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/cn56T/4/)</kbd>

Comment: This seems to work, but only if you manually resize the browser. I'd like it to work if you load the page, and you're already viewing the page with the window less than 950px. - http://jsfiddle.net/cn56T/1/

Comment: @EricWood so do the same thing on doc ready, your code is fine except for the missing closing `)` for resize. But I would not recommend you use replace because you can do the same thing with css media query or you can add a class in js and use that class to hide the words and show the letters which is safer. If you do this, when you resize to bigger screen again you have to do another round of replacement

Comment: This is not right. It fixes what the OP is trying to do but the approach is incorrect. You are replacing the div tags with string literals. Imagine trying to go back when the page is wider... You won't be able to. Your DOM is trashed.

Comment: @PaulSasik, and you are missing this `This seems to work, but only if you manually resize the browser. I'd like it to work if you load the page, and you're already viewing the page with the window less than 950px`

Comment: @RobertRozas perhaps OP can add that requirement to the question, either way replacing the div with text is no good since there is the possibility of resizing back to bigger sizes

Comment: @RobertRozas: No kidding!!! What about the rest of the code you ripped off? **Your first answer didn't work** so you copy mine, tweak the html to text and keep your resize trigger? That is not an answer and not very good SO behavior! The OP could have lifted that call out of the comments and it wasn't the root of the problem at all!

Comment: @PaulSasik, copy, c'mon....the normal thing to do is an else, what other option do i have, a switch for christ sake, c'mon!!

Answer (score 1):

This will work both ways: [Fiddle sample here...](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjum6/) (Run and resize the Result window. 950 is pretty wide actually. You may want to decrease the width for a more realistic test.)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 950) {
        $( "div.sunday" ).html("S");
        $( "div.monday" ).html( "M" );
        $( "div.tuesday" ).html( "T" );
        $( "div.wednesday" ).html( "W" );
        $( "div.thursday" ).html( "T" );
        $( "div.friday" ).html( "F" );
        $( "div.saturday" ).html( "S" );
    } else {
        $( "div.sunday" ).html("Sunday");
        $( "div.monday" ).html( "Monday" );
        $( "div.tuesday" ).html( "Tuesday" );
        $( "div.wednesday" ).html( "Wednesday" );
        $( "div.thursday" ).html( "Thursday" );
        $( "div.friday" ).html( "Friday" );
        $( "div.saturday" ).html( "Saturday" );    
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know if there is any speed difference but I would think using `.text()` would be better for this since only the text is changing

Comment: @Huangism: Yes, text works too: http://jsfiddle.net/9QBrJ/ I doubt if there's any performance difference. In any case, use one or the other.

Comment: This works well. The only problem I'm still having is that I don't want the script to run ONLY if the window is resized. If the window is less than 950px wide when it initially loads, I'd like it to run the script as well. Is that an easy fix?